# Error: spawn ENOTDIR html-pdf in mac

Tags: node.js, meteor, html-pdf

I am using [html-pdf@2.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) in my meteor app. When `.create()` called then following error genereated. **Initially it was working but after updated of Mac Sierra it generate the following error**. However it is working in **ubuntu os**.

```
W20180118-09:52:33.939(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: spawn ENOTDIR
W20180118-09:52:33.940(5.5)? (STDERR)     at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
W20180118-09:52:33.940(5.5)? (STDERR)     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
W20180118-09:52:33.941(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
W20180118-09:52:33.941(5.5)? (STDERR)     at PDF.PdfExec [as exec] (/Users/vineet/fees-mcop-141017/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:87:28)
W20180118-09:52:33.942(5.5)? (STDERR)     at PDF.PdfToBuffer [as toBuffer] (/Users/vineet/fees-mcop-141017/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:44:8)
W20180118-09:52:33.942(5.5)? (STDERR)     at route.js:646:41
W20180118-09:52:33.943(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor/helpers.js:118:1
W20180118-09:52:33.947(5.5)? (STDERR)     at route.js:674:17
W20180118-09:52:33.947(5.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].<anonymous> (route.js:574:29)
W20180118-09:52:33.948(5.5)? (STDERR)     at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
```

### code:-

```
let content = fs.readFileSync(process.env.PWD + '/public/html/itc.html');

            let compiled = template(content);
            let todayDate = moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY');

            let itcPDFCompiled = compiled({
                headername: headerName                   
            });
            let options = {
                format: 'A4',
                "header": { "height": "5mm" },
                "footer": {
                    "height": "8mm",
                    "contents": {
                        default: '<span style="color: #444;float:right;padding:0px 10px;font-size:10px;">' + todayDate + '</span>',
                    }
                }
 };

var requestSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(function (itcPDFCompiled, options, callback) {

  pdf.create(itcPDFCompiled, options).toFile(path + file_name + '.pdf', function (err, res) {
        if (err)
             callback(err);
        else
             callback(null);
     });

});

requestSync(itcPDFCompiled, options);
```

Comment: Did you re-run `meteor npm install` again after the Sierra update? Maybe some changes require the package to be build against the updated environment

Comment: I'm getting this error also. Any luck solving this?

Comment: I am getting this error too!

Answer (score 1):

run

```
npm update
```

in your project folder. It solves my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me after upgrading to Mac OS High Sierra.
`npm install -g phantomjs` followed by `npm rebuild` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be thrown when an underlying library is missing in the system. In my case (mac os x) the missing library was `sshpass`